# Python flatten rows of 2D list

Tags: python, list

Currently working on a program that requires the flattening of columns, rows, and diagonals of a 2D list. I have written the following code that flattens the columns and diagonals but haven't been able to flatten the rows. I am unsure of what I am executing incorrectly.

```
cols = []
rows = []
max_col = len(grid[0])
max_row = len(grid)

for y in range(max_row):
   rows.append(grid[y][x])
   for x in range(max_col):
       cols.append(grid[y][x])
print(cols)
print(rows)

firstDiagonal = [grid[i][i] for i in range(len(grid))]
secondDiagonal = [grid[i][len(grid)-1-i] for i in range(len(grid))]
```

The output resembles:
['G', 'A', 'O', 'C', 'T']['T', 'E', 'B', 'R', 'S']
The row output should be longer mimicking the column output.
['A', 'S', 'T', 'R', 'V', 'Y', 'V', 'B', 'B', 'G']

Comment: What is your starting input?

Comment: can you include an example input and an example output?

Comment: [numpy's ndarray.flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten)

Answer (score 2):

To flatten along the opposite dimension, you need to swap the direction of your loop. If you flatten columns by doing

```
cols = []
for y in range(max_row):
    for x in range(max_col):
        cols.append(grid[y][x])
```

then you flatten rows by doing

```
rows = []
for x in range(max_col):
    for y in range(max_row):
        rows.append(grid[y][x])
```

You can greatly simplify the computation of `cols` using the `extend` method, since the inner loop iterates over the entire row:

```
cols = []
for y in range(max_row):
    cols.extend(grid[y])
```

Or better yet:

```
cols = []
for row in grid:
    cols.extend(row)
```

Such a simplification would not work for `rows`, but you can use the transpose idiom using `zip`:

```
rows = []
for col in zip(*grid):
    rows.extend(col)
```

Finally, each of the expressions can be written as a one-liner using any of the following nested comprehensions:

```
cols = [grid[y][x] for y in range(max_row) for x in range(max_col)]
cols = [item for row in grid for item in row]
rows = [grid[y][x] for x in range(max_col) for y in range(max_row)]
rows = [item for col in zip(*grid) for item in col]
```